# Converting a 5-point Likert scale to 0 to 30 range

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, survey, likert

Hi thanks for viewing my question.

In my research I want to adopt a measure from prior work and apply it to a new context. The question related to a 5- point likert-scale, however, further reading describes "transforming" this scale from ordinal 1-5 to a 0-30 scale. This is then added to another measure to get 0-60.

How is this possible?

---

*"(2) 'Assume that due to a similar development, your department's annual operating budget is reduced by I0 per cent. How significantly will your work be affected over the next year?' 
The subunits whose managers anticipated that output would be unaffected even with a 10 per cent increase in responsibilities or a 10 per cent decline in budget were considered to have higher levels of slack, and those whose managers anticipated a decline in output of 20 per cent or more (disproportionate to the suggested change) were judged to have low levels of slack. Using these transformations, we created a slack measure corresponding to each question with values range from 0 to 30" (page 607)*

Nohria, N. & Gulati, R., 1997. What is the optimum amount of organizational slack?: A study of the relationship between slack and innovation in multinational firms. European Management Journal, 15(6), pp.603–611.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could just multiply by  6, of course. That doesn't change your scale.

Another option is to use the geometric mean of the two numbers. I discuss this in this [blog post](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/measures-of-central-tendency-the-geometric-mean/).

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, multiplying by 6 would give a range of 6-30 as there is no zero score, and the values between 6,12,18 etc have no information.

Comment: Then subtract one and multiply by $7.5$, but I don't see what this accomplishes.  Are you looking for a way to treat the scale as somehow being continuous over $[0, 30]$?  That's not possible without making things up.

Comment: I'm really just trying to understand what was done so that it might be replicated.

I dont think it can be done without making things up, but i have emailed the paper authors to find out.

Thank you very much everyone for taking time to look at this